# Package error after migrating from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I followed guides and posts over the internet, even microsoft documentation. Changed swashbuckle and other stuff, but I am constantly getting this error `Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json`

I have installed NewtonsoftJson, can anyone tell me more about this error?

App is crashing in startup at `MapControllers`:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(ApiLocalization.GetLocalizationOptions());
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(SetupCors);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseEndpoints(options =>
        {
            options.MapControllers();
        });
```

**EDIT**

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="4.5.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire" Version="1.7.17" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Console" Version="1.4.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.5.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah" Version="3.1.66" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" Version="7.9.0.7583">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard.Framework.Core" Version="2.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard.Framework.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
```

I'm not sure if I should remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: @IanKemp Probably, but I stated that so that others knew I did that

Comment: You can share your library `.csproj`,Make sure all your references are upgraded to the new version,

Comment: @Yinqiu Sure, look at edited question. I am sceptical about `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`

Comment: Yes, you can try to delete this.

Comment: You can update all the packages you have installed in your package manager.

Comment: I did, all Microsoft packages, but `Mvc.Core` is at last stable version, so I thought it's okay to use it, I will try it now

Comment: @Yinqiu Still the same problem

Comment: Ok I will try your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your following package references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard.Framework.Core" Version="2.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard.Framework.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
```

You can comment them out and search for them in the package management tool and install the latest version like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard" Version="5.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard.Framework.Core" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Vanguard.Framework.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Comment: You are totally right, now my app is working properly. Can you give me some explanation, like, was problem in fact that Vanguard version `2.4.0` was using .NETStandard 1 and now I have 2.0 or something else?

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is because `MvcJsonOptions` was removed in .NET Core 3.0.It may be that the previous version of `Vanguard` relied on `MvcJsonOptions` in the ASP.NET Core framework. `Vanguard`loaded and tried to find the class, but it did not exist, which caused the error.

Comment: You can see details about this error from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325)

Comment: I read that article, even `breaking changes` on microsoft doc page, where they explained what you just told me, but I didn't even think about vanguard, foolish mistake... Thank you again

Comment: Glad to help you :)